# What is the frequency interval length of k semi-tones?  (k = 1...11)

Tags: theory, tuning, temperament

Go up 12 semi-tones from frequency f on a guitar, and the frequency interval difference in terms of f is f = 2f - f.  What is the formula for the intermediate 11 non-trivial intervals?  So for k=2, that's two semi-tones.  If I start at frequency f on guitar, and go up two frets, what is the frequency interval length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With g being the new frequency, f being the frequency of reference, and k being the interval in number of semitones:

```
g = f * 2ˆ(k/12)
```

With `k = 12` (one octave), you get `g = 2 * f`.

With `k = 0` (unison), you get `g = f`.

In between, you get an exponential curve (power of two).

For the frequency difference between g and f:

```
g - f = f * [2^(k/12) - 1]
```

Note also that k needs not be positive, and may also have decimals. If the interval you are looking for is 3 semitones and 14 cents down, take `k = -3.14`.